# paste linux script

Tags: linux, bash

I have a small question and would appreciate your help in it please.

I need to merge different text files together using paste command as :

```
paste -d, ~/Desktop/*.txt  > ~/Desktop/Out/merge.txt
```

However, the files got merged out of order. (text files are numbered 1, 2, 3, etc.)

I am using `*.txt` since different number of files exist for different scenarios.

Would you mind helping me in it please.

Comment: `paste -d, ~/Desktop/{1..314}.txt  > ~/Desktop/Out/merge.txt` if you're using bash and your text files are numbered sequentially.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. the thing is I dont know the number of the files for each time I use Paste command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a rather long way of doing the same but in one line.

```
paste -d, $(ls ~/Desktop/*.txt | awk -F/ '{print $NF"/"$0}' | sort -n | cut -d/ -f2-) > ~/Desktop/merge.txt
```

I like one liners :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you use modern bash you can write:

```
paste -d, ~/Desktop/{1..10}.txt  > ~/Desktop/Out/merge.txt
```

If not, you must use something like:

```
paste -d, $(seq 1 10 | sed 's@.*@~/Desktop/&.txt) > ~/Desktop/Out/merge.txt
```

If you don't know which files you have in the directory,
you can list and sort them:

```
cd ~/Desktop/
paste -d, $(ls -1d *.txt| sort -n) > ~/Desktop/Out/merge.txt
```

Example:

```
$ touch {1..20}.txt
$ echo $(ls -1 | sort -n)
1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt 5.txt 6.txt 7.txt 8.txt 9.txt 10.txt 11.txt 12.txt 13.txt 14.txt 15.txt 16.txt 17.txt 18.txt 19.txt 20.txt
```

Example2:

```
$ echo hello > 1.txt
$ echo dear > 5.txt
$ echo friend > 11.txt
$ paste -d, $(ls -1d *.txt| sort -n)
hello,dear,friend
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. But the answer is giving me wrong output result. each file has a single column, I need to merge these files with "," between each file.

Comment: I missed `,` adter `-d`. Please check my answer once again. And I added another example

Answer (score 0):

```
paste -d, $(ls ~/Desktop/*.txt) > ~/Desktop/Out/merge.txt
```

The * is being replaced by an alphabetically sorted list of filenames of your directory.

> #### [3.5.8 Filename Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-pathname-expansion-95)
>
> Bash scans each word for the characters ‘*’, ‘?’, and ‘[’. If one of these characters appears, then the word is regarded as a pattern, and replaced with an alphabetically sorted list of file names matching the pattern.

So the filenaming does not have to be consecutive ;)

Comment: Michael, your answer is obviously wrong. I don't want minus it, but your solution is wrong -- the list will not be numerically sorted. Also, you don't need `ls` in your soultion at all. You could write simple `*.txt` instead.

Comment: Thanks Mate :)) Do appreciate it